# Child process executes statements written before fork call

Tags: c, fork, ipc

I am creating the child process in my code. When i call the fork(), child process should start its execution from next statement, but in my code, child process executes the statement before the fork call.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int pid;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("oh.txt","w");
fprintf(fp,"i am before fork\n");
pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
                fprintf(fp,"i am inside child block\n");
        }
        else{
                fprintf(fp,"i inside parent block\n");
        }
fprintf(fp,"i am inside the common block to both parent and child\n");
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

This is the output which i get

## OUTPUT:

```
i am before fork
i inside parent block
i am inside the common block to both parent and child
i am before fork
i am inside child block
i am inside the common block to both parent and child
```

The line "i am before fork" should be written once in the file but it is written twice by child and parent.
Why it is so?

Thank you.

Comment: Add a `fflush(fp)` before you fork off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a buffering issue. `fprintf` doesn't write to the file immediately, but buffers the output. When you `fork`, you end up with two copies of the buffer.

Try doing an `fflush(fp)` before forking and see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is because you print with `fprintf`, it gets buffered but not printed, and then it gets printed in child process when buffer is flushed.